# Ошибка при отправке запроса API ВКонтакте

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, api

Есть простой код запроса на python с API ВКонтакте, который возвращает пользователя по id:

```
import requests

api_url='https://api.vk.com/method/'
token = '###'

response = requests.get(api_url+'users.get?user_ids=1&fields=bdate&access_token='+token+'v=5.80')

result = response.text
print(result)
```

Вывод такой:

```
{"error":{"error_code":5,"error_msg":"User authorization failed: invalid access_token (4).","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"users.get"},{"key":"user_ids","value":"1"},{"key":"fields","value":"bdate"}]}}
```

Как это исправить?
Токен получал посредством создания `Standalone` приложения и перехода по ссылке:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id={IDприложения}&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=friends,photos,audio,video,docs,notes,pages,status,wall,groups,messages,notifications,offline&response_type=token
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Убедитесь, что у вас запрос составлен верно:

```
>>> import requests
>>> token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
>>> base_url = "https://api.vk.com/method"
>>> r = requests.get(f"{base_url}/users.get?user_ids=1&fields=bdate&access_token={token}&v=5.80")
>>> r.json()
{'response': [{'bdate': '10.10.1984', 'first_name': 'Павел', 'id': 1, 'last_name': 'Дуров'}]}
```

В вашем запросе перед указанием версии не хватает символа амперсанда `&v=5.80`.